# Bound on Minimal Length of Vectors in Lattice and its Dual Lattice

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, lattices, euclidean-lattices

Let $\Lambda$ be a lattice in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Lambda^\ast$ its dual lattice. Let $d=\min_{v\in\Lambda} (v,v)$ and $d^\ast =\min_{v\in\Lambda^\ast} (v,v)$ be the minimal squared lengths of vectors in the two lattices. I'm interested in lattices in which both $d$ and $d^\ast$ are large.
For $n=24$, I know of the self-dual Leech lattice which has $d=d^\ast=4$. I'd like to find lattices with $d,d^\ast\ge 8$. Is this at all possible? Self-duality is not so important for me, so if I can lower $n$ at the expense of self-duality that's OK.

Comment: So $d=d_*=8$ is possible for $n=72$ and an integral self-dual lattice (thanks Yoav!). Can one find a lattice with an arbitrary large $\min(d,d_*)$? Can one find a lattice with $d=d_*\ge 8$ and $n<72$ abandoning integrality and/or self-duality?

Comment: The Conway-Thompson theorem asserts the existence of unimodular lattices of arbitrarily large minimal norm.  Indeed, the maximal minimal norm for unimodular lattices of rank $r$ can be bounded below by a function that is asymptotic to $\frac{r}{2\pi e}$.

Answer (score 3):

The [table of unimodular lattices](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/unimodular.html) suggests this is possible for n = 72.

Comment: Do you know what $N$ and $M$ stand for in the table?

Comment: No, I was wondering the same.

Answer (score 3):

The product $d\times d^*$ cannot be "so" large, as a consequence of the so-called  [Transference theorems](http://fma2.math.uni-magdeburg.de/~henk/lectures/diskrete%20geometrie/seminar/banaszczyk&new%20bounds%20in%20some%20transference%20theorems%20in%20the%20geometry%20of%20numbers.pdf?origin=publication_detail) Particularly, Thm. 2.1. of the paper shows that  $d\times d^* \leq n^2$ (hence in your example, $n$ should be at least $8$). So the best you can do in terms of the product is $\Omega(n^2)$. The aforemetioned Conway-Thompson Theorem (see [1], p. 46) shows that indeed it *is* possible to achieve $\Omega(n^2)$.

In the case of $d, d^* \geq 8$, we have the lower bound $n \geq 8$ and the achievable upper bound $72$ (due to the unimodular table). Nevertheless, there is still a huge gap between both bounds. I am not aware of any result that shows that smaller $n$ are possible.

[1]. J. Milnor and D. Husemoller, ``Symmetric Bilinear Forms,'' Springer-Verlag, New York,
1973

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. It seems to me that the $\lambda$'s in the transference theorem you cite are rather the square roots of my $d$'s, so that the theorem implies $d \times d^*\le n^2$. So it seems that this still allows $d,d^*\ge 8$ and $n$ as low as 8.

Comment: Indeed by Minkowski there are unimodular lattices with
$d_\min = d^*_\min \gg n$, so $n^2$ is the right asymptotic growth.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: is this Minkowki result the same as Conway-Thompson? Can you please give a reference?

Comment: I don't know what's "Conway-Thompson" but it does give the same
$r/(2\pi e)$ asymptotic.  Sorry I don't have a reference at my fingertips,
but Minkowski = the mass formula saying that the average of theta functions
$\theta_L$, weighted by $\left|{\rm Aut}(L)\right|^{-1}$, 
is an Eisenstein series.  Yet another approach is to calculate that
for each $\delta>0$ an average lattice $L$ has minimal norm at least
$r/(2\pi e) - \delta r$ with probability $1 - \epsilon$ with 
$\epsilon \to 0$ as $r \to \infty$, so the same is true for both
$L$ and $L^*$ with probability at least $1 - 2\epsilon$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies This probability method is interesting. How do you define an average lattice? In whatever definition, I presume $L^*$ and $L$ are not independent, so your final step may be not allowed.

Comment: The final step is fine as long as $L$ and $L^*$ have the same distribution:
I claimed at least $1-2\epsilon$, not $(1-\epsilon)^2$.  "Average lattice"
has a natural definition if you regard the space of natural lattices as
a double coset space, the quotient of ${\rm SL}_r({\bf R})$ by 
${\rm SO}_r({\bf R})$ on one side and ${\rm SL}_r({\bf Z})$ on the other,
starting from the invariant measure on the quotient by ${\rm SO}_r({\bf R})$.

Comment: You can also approximate this distribution by random index-$p$ subsets of
${\bf Z}^r$ for large primes $p$ (a nontrivial claim, but for the present
purpose it's enough to check that this yields $L$ for which neither 
$L$ nor $L^*$ is likely to have a short vector).

Comment: It seems that all averaging "Minkowski-Hlawka" type of arguments leads to $r/(2\pi e)$. This is asymptotically ok, but for finite (and small $n$) it seems loose...